# Implementation difference of String.substring() between JDK 6 and JDK 7

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

I heard that String.substring() in Java has some implementation difference between JDK 6 and JDK 7. Can somebody shed some light on the improvements or risks that would be resulted from this change? Is it a JVM level change or class level change?

My question is, why is this change and the potential risks associated with it.

Comment: This is the second result for googling "java 7 substring" and it explains it pretty well: [Here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/)

Comment: I believe it was actually in some update within Java 7 - so the *initial* release of Java 7 behaved like Java 6.

Comment: Do you see any impact on the code point